# Dragging Formulas into next blank column and pasting values on previous column

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I'm looking to use a macro to drag formulas from the end column to the next blank column and then paste values on the previous column.

For example, column V contains the formulas at first. I want to then drag these formulas into column W (blank column) and Paste Values in column V, but I want to write the code in a way that when it comes to using the macro again the formulas that are now in column W will be dragged into column X and then have their values pasted in column X.

This is what I've got so far:

```
Sub RollFile()
Columns("V3:V114").Select
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Columns("V3:W114"), Type:=xlFillDefault
Columns("V3:V114").Select
Selection.Copy
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Range("W2").Select
End Sub
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend using the `Range.Cells` property- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-cells-property-excel

Essentially, `Columns("V3:V114")` in your code would be replaced by something like

```
Range(Cells(3, 22), Cells(114, 22))
```

Now you can use variables instead of the numbers to iterate using a loop.